# How should an API on the same host be implemented through PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I have tried googling for related topics for this but was unable to find anything that answered my question so here I am.

I am going to be building a REST API for my web based application to improve scalability and allow me to easily implement site updates and build other applications. However, in my research I have not been able to figure out a way to use this API within PHP itself. As it currently stands, the API will not be public and will be hosted on the same server as the website hence my question.

The website currently uses PHP to load in content server side and then JavaScript to dynamically add content and embellish the user experience. I would like to keep it this way but have all requests including PHP ones to go through the API. Obviously the JavaScript will use an HTTP request going to a specific endpoint e.g "htp://example.com/user/123" but it seems cumbersome to do the same process using curl with PHP when the API is on the same host.

If I understand correctly removing the HTTP request from the mix will mean that it is not restfull but that is not an issue. So:

**1:** How should I make calls to the API from PHP?

**2:**  How should I maintain the user session? Bearing in mind that the session should not be maintained by the API and JavaScript will send all neccesary data for authentication with the API call.

Comment: You don't need to use the API via PHP of course, access the DB directly [or whichever other persistence layer], the same way the API code does.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use Zend HTTP [Rest Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.0/en/zend.rest.client.html) - it is having powerful rest architecture
2. Yes - you are right, you cannot maintain sessions when using API, so try to use another way for maintaining authorization like create some class which will check your authorization based on the API response
3. Use some kind of token which is unique for each user and pass it with header authorization.

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned, and this will probably get some abuse. I don't want to use an API framework mainly bpfor intellectual curiosity. I would like to build it from scratch

Comment: Then either make a curl call or create your own structure using OOPS concept - make a use of classes and objects as if you are working on same host then you don't need to call API for it :)